# How to round out edges?

Tags: modeling

Okay so this is my very first character i've started to make and I need a little bit of guidance if you guys do not mind, How could I curve the sides of the shoes to make them more realistic looking? because right now I feel like it is throwing off my whole model.  Thanks! :) [image: The shoes are not rounded on the edge and drop at a 90 degree angle]

Comment: Reference images is what most people of all standards dig up first. The initial outcome with realism has a lot to do with topology. That'll at least get rid of some resistance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the flat shaded look, then you'll just have to model more edge loops and achieve the rounded look with the actual topology.

Otherwise, you might be better adding a Subsurf modifier to get smoother surfaces and curved edges. If you want to keep some edges sharper you'll need to add edge loops near the corners to keep them sharp (or you can set the Sharpness value on the polygon edges alternatively).

Answer (score 1):

Your model takes its form from the mesh structure you define for it. That means that with only a few basic vertices/edges/faces, your model will look very block-like. To define it better, you add more vertices/edges/faces where they're needed.

There are a number of tools to use for doing this, but the most useful one in your case is the Loop Cut and Slide tool, which will allow you to add more rings of vertices/edges to your mesh.

You should also add the subsurface modifier to get that really smooth look, but do this only after you've added some more rings to your mesh, or it will deform too much.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers say, add loop cuts to the part you would like to make it smooth by using  Ctrl-R (place the mouse pointer in the required spot hovering the place to be smoothened).

Then use your scroll to increase the number of cuts.

it is also recommended to use subdivision modifier under modifiers section.